# how to cast diagramitem into diagramconnector

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to cast diagramItem into DiagramConnector in order to get begin and end Items of the connector

DiagramConnector conn = new DiagramConnector();

```
        if (Equals(diagramControl1.SelectedItems[0].ToString(), conn.ToString()))
        {

           conn = diagramControl1.SelectedItems[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The DiagramConnector class inherits from DiagramItem, so you can directly cast it:

```
DiagramConnector connector = (DiagramConnector)diagramControl.SelectedItems[0];

// or

DiagramConnector connector = (diagramControl.SelectedItems[0] as DiagramConnector);
```

There is no need to create a new instance of a DiagramConnector.